# How can I learn A/B testing independently?

Tags: user-research, ab-testing

I'm looking for an independent project to learn A/B testing on, and I'm trying to figure out which A/B testing tools are commonly used for:

1. Mobile
2. Games
3. Web

And I'm also aware that the common programs are not always the best - what common problems are common in the common programs?

Comment: Welcome to the UX Stack Exchange!  Your post asks three separate questions, but it's best to just ask one.  Please have a look at our [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) to see what makes a question suitable for this site.  Your first and third questions aren't good fits for here because they have no one correct answer.  You might try asking them in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) (once you get 20 rep) instead.  The second question is inappropriate because it's a [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) (and is 3 separate questions).

Comment: This question will almost certainly be closed, but after familiarizing yourself with the site guidelines, please feel welcome to ask another instead.